# Active Directory Federation Services Logout

Tags: adfs

I am using ADFS 3.0 version , with SAML . ADFS authenticates user and send me SAML tokens . But when I logout from ADFS using this URL https://aptifydev2.aptify.com/adfs/ls/?wa=wsignout1.0 I am unable to logout . ADFS shows me you are successfully logout but If I login my application again it does not ask for credentials . All AuthN request and Logout request are signed with certificate.

I can see "MSISSignoutProtocol" cookie is added in browser which is preventing me from Logout.Please let me know how to expire individual session from ADFS.

Answer (score 1):

Good discussion [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1439.ad-fs-how-to-invoke-a-ws-federation-sign-out.aspx).

The key is that when your app receives wa=wsignoutcleanup1.0, it needs to clear out its own cookies.

Answer (score 0):

I know its old thread but to help others, I solved my issue by deleting the JSESSIONID cookie before hitting the ADFS logout URL, so, try deleting your session id cookie and then hit ADFS logout URL